# Analytical models for planetary nebula expantion

Tags: fluid-dynamics, astrophysics, astronomy, nebulae

I'm doing an astrophysics project where we measure the properties of a planetary nebula (NGC 7662) where we need to determine it's electronic temperature, electronic density and expansion speed.

I'm trying to find some (simple) analytical models that could link our different parameters. or that could help us determine other parameters of the nebula using our parameters (for example using expansion speed to determine mass loss rate).

In short, I need some simple analytical models for nebula expansion but I'm not able to find good resources on them. Could somebody provided a good reference?(article or book)

Comment: Have you looked at Lamers' [*Introduction to Stellar Winds*](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Stellar-Winds-Henny-Lamers/dp/0521595657)?